# android performance issue

Tags: android

my android application works well but it's performance(speed) is slow. In my logcat i saw frequent garbage collection operation  like

11-02 15:07:20.647: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12571): GC freed 295 objects / 38448 bytes in 93ms

Is this the reason for low performance?? How can i improve my applications performance???
anybody please help

Comment: hard to say without knowing your app. are you using lots of images? liveviews? what kind of app?

Comment: frequent garbage collection is an indication of potential memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the emulator don't worry - it is slow by itself. GC is not responcible for this i think, 93 ms is time you won't even notice. So try your application at the real phone and if there are preformance issues - use the profiler.

Comment: @vladmir   i tried with real phone. i happens the same...         @Mathias   my application is to download images from server,displaying them,When user touch that image do some background calculation based on touch position

Comment: From developer.android.com site, i have seen that the one of reasons for low performance is allocating objects in userinterface loop. i allocated most of them in OnCreate() method of my activity. Is Oncreate() in UI loop??

Comment: @asifkt, what about the background applications? when the loww performance takes place?

Comment: overall perfrmance is low. backgroung operatios is to compare the touch position with an array of positions.. i think there is no faults with logic that i have used there.. i used the same code that my friend used in his j2me appliation. that works very well

Comment: onCreate is called when you activity is firstly constructed. Do you allocate the memmory for images in onCreate()? please, show the code.

Comment: No. i created objects for view(imageView, button,listView). Should i implement onStart() and onResume() methods??

Comment: GC freeing occurs when program calls the methods like object.setName(new String(ch, start, length)); Anybody know substitute method to avoid this to happen?? this method is frequently called  in my application, and consumes around 110ms for each calling to GC freeing..

Comment: why do you need new String creation?

Answer (score 0):

Your application performance in terms of user interface and memory is quite related.

In this case 93ms means that your device could be dropping about 6 frames in the ideal scenario. If the GC is executed often this could be a problem.

The Android ART/Dalvik virtual machine is a version of the Java Virtual Machine where the Garbage Collector implementation is based on generations. This means that your application process has a heap associated separated by different generations where the GC is going to act once a generation is full. You can think of these generations as buckets or arrays of memory.

Once a generation is full the Android virtual machine will start the garbage collector process. As the Android virtual machine can not collect and fragment your application heap while the app process is running the garbage collector event will stop all the threads in your app while the garbage collector is working. That's why your application can be dropping frames if the app garbage collector is invoked so repeatedly.

Here you have an example:

Last week I discovered my app was leaking memory. I discovered this because after 20 minutes using my app I noticed the UI was performing really slow. Closing/opening an activity or scrolling a RecyclerView was really slow. After monitoring some of my users in production using http://flowup.io/ I found this:

[image]

The frame time was really really high and the frames per second really really low. You can see that some frames needed about 2 seconds to render :S.

Trying to figure it out what was causing this bad frame time/fps I discovered I had a memory issue as you can see here:

[image]

Even when the average memory consumption was close to the 15MB at the same time the app was dropping frames.

That's how I discovered the UI issue. I had a memory leak in my app causing a lot of garbage collector events and that's was causing the bad UI performance because the Android VM had to stop my app to collect memory every single frame.

Looking at the code I had a leak inside a custom view because I was not unregistering a listener registered into a Android Choreographer instance. After releasing the fix, everything became normal :)

If your app is dropping frames due to a memory issue you should review two common errors:

- Review if your app is allocating objects inside a method invoked multiple times per second. An example could be creating new instances of an object inside a onDraw custom view method.
- Review if your app is registering an instance into the Android SDK but not releasing it. Registering a listener into a bus event could also be possible leak.

**Disclaimer: The tool I've been using to monitor my app is under development. I have access to this tool because I'm one of the developers :) If you want access to this tool we will release a beta version soon! You can join in our web site: http://flowup.io/.**

If you want to use different tools you can use: traveview, dmtracedump, systrace or the Andorid performance monitor integrated into Android Studio. But remember that this tools will monitor your connected device and not the rest of your user devices or Android OS installations.